# Mysql migrate huge db from innodb to ndbcluster err: the table is full

Tags: mysql, innodb, cluster-computing

I'm trying to migrate old database to mysql cluster (4 data nodes) by using command:

```
ALTER TABLE sample ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
The table '#sql-7ff3_3' is full
```

There are approximately 300 mil rows in this table. Here are my config file:

```
/mysql-cluster/config.ini
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataDir=/data/mysql-cluster/ndb/
BackupDataDir=/data/mysql-cluster/backup/
DataMemory=10G
IndexMemory=5G
TimeBetweenLocalCheckpoints=6
FragmentLogFileSize=256MB
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=50
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=8000
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
MaxNoOfTables = 10000
RedoBuffer=128M
MaxNoOfAttributes=5000
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=1024


/etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
basedir=/usr/local/mysql
datadir=/data/mysql-cluster/mysqld/
event_scheduler=on
default-storage-engine=ndbcluster
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=192.168.x.x,192.168.x.x
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512MB
key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
table_cache = 1024
read_buffer_size = 512M
```

Answer (score 1):

You hit a limit on a temporary table, either num_rows, disk space or tablespace.

Try adding 'MAX_ROWS=1000000000' to your alter table.

Check if 'tmpdir' points to a disk with enough space.

Then look at the value of 'tmp_table_size'.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size
If you cannot increase it any further, dig down in
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-size-limit.html

Finally, MySQL Cluster tablespaces and log file groups are not implemented as files. Did you allocate enough space using CREATE/ALTER TABLESPACE?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data-objects.html